# How do I open a window that I have created with Winforms in my code

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Winforms window design that I made and I want to test it. I want to open it via a right click. What do I need to call in order to open this new window?

Something like this:

```
    private void openBlackHoleSingularity_Click(object sender EventArgs e)
    {
      bool failed = false;

       //Open StartSingularity.cs???

     if(failed)
     { MessageBox.Show(this, "Need more Antimatter!"); return;}
    }
```

I know this is a very Googleable question, but I am not very good at GoogleFu yet, and I am not really getting a definitive answer. I apologize in advance for the stupid question.

Comment: You probably want a `new StartSingularity()` and a `Show()` or `ShowDialog()`.  But there are lots of different possible combinations such as (create a new window every time, or save the results of `new StartSingularity()` and re-show the same window if it has been hidden) (place the window in the center of the screen, or move it to where the mouse is) and so on.

Comment: Yeah it was something like that. I have been doing too much functional programming lately, and this has caused me to get rusty in basic fundamentals. Wake up call to do more personal programming! Thank you for your input, it is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it's just creating an object and for some reason I just didn't even think to do that.

For fellow lads and lasses who are learning it is:

```
 StartSingularityForm createBlackHole = new StartSingularityForm();
 createBlackHole.Show();
```

Comment: Yep, that's how you do it.